# How do I solve the inequality $x<x^2-12<4x$?

Tags: inequality

So first I considered 
$x < x^2 -12$
so I get $0 < x^2 - x -12$
which is $0<(x+3)(x-4)$

after this I don't know where to go

Again, I considered $x^2 - 12< 4x$
which is $x^2 - 4x - 12<0$
so $(x+2)(x-6)<0$

Again same issue, I don't know where to after that.

Comment: You may look [here](http://virtualnerd.com/algebra-2/quadratics/inequalities/graphing-solving-inequalities/solve-inequality-algebraically)

Comment: After you got the inequality $0<(x+3)(x-4)$, the next step is to remember that a product of two real numbers is positive if and only if the two factors are either both positive or both negative.  Also, in this particular problem, it might be useful to notice, before working on the quadratic inequalities, that you'll only be dealing with positive values of $x$ because any solution will have $x<4x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to solve the system of quadratic inequalities
\begin{cases}
x^2-x-12>0 ,\\
x^2-4x-12<0 .
\end{cases}
The first quadratic polynomial has roots $4$ and $-3$, hence the solutions of the first inequation is
$$S_1=(-\infty,-3)\cup(4,\infty).$$
As to the second quadratic polynomial, it has roots $6$ and $-2$, so the solution of the second inequation is
$$S_2=(-2, 6),$$
and the solutions of the system is
$$S_1\cap S_2=(4,6).$$

Comment: Thank you so much! the last part cleared my doubt completely!!

Answer (score 1):

$$0 < (x+3)(x-4)$$

is equivalent to $x < -3$ or $x >4$. To see this sketch the convex quadratic curve and see where is it positive.

Similarly,
$$(x+2)(x-6) < 0$$ is equivalent to $$-2 < x<6.$$

Intersecting them, the region of interest is

$$4 < x< 6.$$

[image]